# Image not displaying in A-Frame version 8 (only version 2)

Tags: aframe, webvr

I am really new to A-Frame and try to display an image. I got this done with version 2 from a youtube tutorial, but when I change the version to 3 or higher (I always need to use the most recent version, currently 8) it is not displaying anymore, but seems loaded.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.2.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <a-scene>
        <a-assets>
          <img id="image" src="winterOriginal.jpg">
        </a-assets>
      <a-image src="#image" width="16" height="9"></a-image>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `crossorigin` attribute for the `img` resource:

```
<img id="image" src="image.jpg" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

to satisfy the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) policy.

- 0.2.0 [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dLag76u2/),
- 8.2.0 [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6tfx48jp/1/).